# How to resolve runtime error for VBA Loop

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a macro that loops through cells. My range starts at at `$A1` but I need it to work for a range starting at `$A8`. How can I fix my code:

```
Sub test()
    Dim a, i As Long, ii As Long, dic As Object
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dic.CompareMode = 1
    a = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Value
    For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
        If Not dic.exists(a(i, 1)) Then
            Set dic(a(i, 1)) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            dic(a(i, 1)).CompareMode = 1
        End If
        dic(a(i, 1))(a(i, 2)) = dic(a(i, 1))(a(i, 2)) + a(i, 3)
    Next
    With Sheets("sheet2").Cells(1).CurrentRegion
        .Offset(1, 1).ClearContents
        a = .Value
        For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
            If dic.exists(a(i, 1)) Then
                For ii = 2 To UBound(a, 2)
                 a(i, ii) = dic(a(i, 1))(a(1, ii)) + 0
             Next
            End If
        Next
        .Value = a: .Parent.Activate
    End With
```

End Sub

Comment: Welcome, Jose. This is no the correct site for your question. If you click the question mark at the top right of any of our sites then you can find out what is on topic for that site. In this case, programming questions belong on https://stackoverflow.com/  Good luck  (btw, is it as simple as changing `UBound(a, 1)` to `UBound(a, 8)`?

Comment: @Mawg - Maybe, as long as `a` resolves to the string `A`.

Comment: Lol! Well, I am no VBA programmer. But S.O should be able to sort him out